# Text at right side of slide

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to include some text at the right side of a beamer slide/frame, like so

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hfill
\begin{description}
    \item[item1] description1 text
    \item[item2] description2 text
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However this results in the description at the left side of the slide…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting stuff in columns. (Beamer manual -- 12.7 Splitting a Frame into Multiple Columns). This way you can later add content to the left side later if you wish so.

Example from the manual

```
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{5cm} Two\\lines.
\end{column}
\begin{column}{5cm} One line (but aligned).
\end{column}
\end{columns}
```

The below example does *not* use the environment version of the command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]%beamer
\column{0.5\textwidth}
% blank
\column{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{description}
        \item[item1] description1 text
        \item[item2] description2 text
        \item[item1] description1 text
        \item[item2] description2 text descriptiotn text
                     description2 text descriptiotn text
                     description2 text descriptiotn text
    \end{description}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: columns]

You can also use a `minipage` and `\hfill`. This requires minimum change to your MWE. But it may be difficult to utilise the left side of the slide later on.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[]{7cm}
        \begin{description}
            \item[item1] description1 text
            \item[item2] description2 text
            \item[item1] description1 text
            \item[item2] description2 text descriptiotn text
            description2 text descriptiotn text
            description2 text descriptiotn text
        \end{description}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: minipage right side]

Comment: Do you know why the `\hfill` doesn't work on the `description` environment directly?

Comment: I guess that the `description` environment adds a new line before its starts and so your `hfill` is not on the same line as the description environment and hence has no effect. When you put it in a `minipage` or a `parbox`, the extra vertical space added by the `description` environment is inside a *box* and the `hfill` is in the same line as the *box*. More over the *box* doesn't take up the full width of the page and latex algorithm gets some slack to expand the `hfill`.